# math symbols don't work within PHP class definitions?

Tags: php, syntax-error

I am receiving the error:

Message : syntax error, unexpected '*', expecting ',' or ';'

when I try to use math symbols to define a variable inside a class.  For example,

```
class Foo {
    public static $test = 1+1;
}

echo Foo::$test;
```

yields this error.  Is it possible to use math within class variable definitions in PHP?

Comment: No. You'd have to do this in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expression isn't allowed as field default value. You may try this

```
class Foo {
    public static $test;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->test = 1+1;
    }
}

echo Foo::$test;
```

Comment: I see, so I should use the constructor.  Explanation is in the docs - http://us1.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Comment: yes or in getter and setter